# Error al deployar sistema symfony: Uncaught LogicException: Extension DOM is required

Tags: apache, symfony, symfony4, deployment

Desarrolle un sistema con symfony 5 y ahora hice el despliegue en el hosting. Migre los archivos por fpt y todo perfecto. Sin embargo, al ejecutar el sistema me genera el siguiente error:

```
 Uncaught LogicException: Extension DOM is required.
```

El sistema en el hosting esta en php 7.4
Por otro lado, mi archivo index esta configurado como:

```
<?php

  use App\Kernel;
  use Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Debug;
  use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

 require '/home12/eisenluk/symfony/config/bootstrap.php'; 
 require '/home12/eisenluk/symfony/vendor/autoload.php';

if ($_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']) {
   umask(0000);

   Debug::enable();
 }

if ($trustedProxies = $_SERVER['TRUSTED_PROXIES'] ?? $_ENV['TRUSTED_PROXIES'] ?? false) {
  Request::setTrustedProxies(explode(',', $trustedProxies), Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_ALL ^      Request::HEADER_X_FORWARDED_HOST);
 }

if ($trustedHosts = $_SERVER['TRUSTED_HOSTS'] ?? $_ENV['TRUSTED_HOSTS'] ?? false) {
   Request::setTrustedHosts([$trustedHosts]);
}
$kernel = new Kernel($_SERVER['APP_ENV'], (bool) $_SERVER['APP_DEBUG']);
$request = Request::createFromGlobals();
$response = $kernel->handle($request);
$response->send();
$kernel->terminate($request, $response);
```

Por otro lado mi archivo .htacces setee mi env:

```
SetEnv APP_ENV prod
SetEnv DATABASE_URL 'mysql://eisenluk_user:Hm2DsQL9h@Dj@127.0.0.1:3306/eisenluk_sql'
```

Si me pueden orientar sobre como configurarlo, gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece que te falta la extensión DOM, como indica el mensaje de error

https://www.php.net/manual/es/intro.dom.php

Si tu servidor corre sobre Ubuntu, la podes instalar ejecutando:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install php-xml
```

Sino deberías ver cómo instalar esa extensión de PHP en el S.O. que corra tu hosting. 
Saludos